# Java code and iText PDF library will not display shipping label image in browser

Tags: java, image, itext, byte, apache-commons

I have a Java method that when called, displays a shipping label pdf image in my browser. I'm using iText, as well as Apache Commons libraries for this.

```
import org.jasypt.contrib.org.apache.commons.codec_1_3.binary.Base64;
import com.itextpdf.text.*;

...

public void constructLabel(HttpServletResponse response) {
    Document document = new Document();
    byte[] image = null;
    Image labelImage = null;
    try {
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
        document.open();
        String base64Label = "a3B4GHHh6Y0m923xKj="; //<--This is longer, but I shortened it for this question
        image = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Label.getBytes());
        labelImage = Image.getInstance(image);
        labelImage.setAlignment(Image.TOP);
        labelImage.scalePercent(new Float("35"));
        document.add(labelImage);
        response.getOutputStream().write(image);
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(image.length);
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
...
```

For UPS labels, it works fine. When my code runs a base-64 encoded UPS label, the label displays in the browser. But for FedEx labels, I get an error modal in the browser that says "Error    Failed to load PDF document." Please see pictures of the labels (printed from an online PDF converter) and error modal below.

This has me left in the dark in that there are no errors or exceptions or stack traces in the console at all.

How can I get this code to show a PDF image of the FedEx label in the browser?

[image: UPS Label]

[image: FedEx Label]

[image: Browser Error]

Comment: Do you only need to display a label image in a browser, without printing it? Do you do anything else with the pdf?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I only need to display a label image in the browser. I don't need anything else with the PDF.

Comment: Keep it simple. Use a barcode library if you want to make barcode images, use a PDF library if you want to make PDF files (iText uses some code from the ZXing barcode library). The Fedex label appears to contain PDF417 (the 2D barcode), I can't identify the linear barcode on sight.

Comment: I am using the iText library for PDF files though.